# Check a string to see if it contains an array, if so output the value from the array into a new variable

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I'm fairly new to PHP and struggling to understand the best way to do this. I have an array:

```
$colours= array('Yellow', 'Red', 'Blue');
```

I now need to check a string against this array and if one of the colors exists in the string we then need to output the result into a new variable. Here's a sample string:

```
$string= "Black & Aztec Blue";
```

So in this case the desired output would be "Blue". Or, as suggested below both values could be saved in a second array? Has anyone done something like this before?

All help appreciated.

Comment: You could explode on spaces then iterate through each value. If you had two found values would you want both or just the first one?

Comment: @chris85 great idea, but some of the strings may contain nospaces or slashes instead of spaces etc... Very messy data! eg. "Red/Tarmac Black" ideally this would be Red as Black is a secondary colour. I guess both would be good. Perhaps as another array?

Comment: http://php.net/strpos http://php.net/foreach

Comment: Do you know the list of ALL possible separation characters?

Comment: Oh, yea @MarcB's idea is better. Iterate through your colors and use strpos on the string for matches.

Comment: @FirstOne - scanning the data I can see slashes, dashes, nospaces and spaces.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's a nospace? something like this `BlackBlue`?

Comment: @FirstOne yes - sorry thats what I mean.

Comment: Or you also could do a regex approach. https://eval.in/445627

Comment: Ok, so first you I suggest you to set a default separation characters and make every other into the selected one. Example, make `/`,`-`[...] become `(space)`. Only then process the data.

Comment: Last resource would be loop letter by letter from the original text and then check if the word formed with `position + word_length` from each color from `$colors` is the same;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a regexp that matches any of the words using alternation `|`.

```
$regexp = '/\b(' . implode('|', $colours) . ')\b/'; // $regexp = '/\b(Yellow|Red|Blue)\b/'
if (preg_match($regexp, $string, $match)) {
    $found_word = $match[0];
}
```

`\b` matches word boundaries, so this will not match if the strings are adjacent like `BlackBlue`. Take them out if you want to match the colours in this case.

Comment: Will this find if two words are connected like `BlackBlue Red`?

Comment: No. The `\b` operator only matches at word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for this @Barmar. I might be able to hack this to work. Is there a way of getting it to work regardless of case? As some of the words are uppercase and mixed case.

Comment: Add the `i` modifier to the regexp.

Comment: Maybe before asking any more questions, you should brush up on the documentation of using regexp in PHP?

Comment: @barmar - advice taken. I've not touched regexp before so please find it within yourself to excuse my naivety.

Comment: Several days ago I saw a answer of you about check a string for existing multiple value, your answer was something like this: `strpos($str,array('val1', 'val2')` or maybe you were used `strstr()`. Anyway, how can I find it again?

Comment: @Sajad You can search for **user:1491895 strpos** and sort by date